# WSGI can't find file in same directory in app

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, apache2, wsgi

I'm trying to set up a Ubuntu server with apache2 and wsgi but I get a 500 internal error. WSGI can't find the file "client_secrets.json".

App structure

```
/var/www/FlaskApp/
  flaskapp.wsgi
  - FlaskApp
      - static
        // All js, css, imgs and fonts
      - templates
        // All templates in here
      __init__.py
      client_secrets.json
      database_setup.py
      starter_content.py
```

**init**.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

CLIENT_ID = json.loads(
    open('client_secrets.json', 'r').read())['web']['client_id']
APPLICATION_NAME = "Catalog App"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super_secret_key'
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

flaskapp.wsgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'MY_SECRET_KEY'
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName SERVER_IP
    ServerAdmin email@email.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log:
[image: error.png]

Comment: Why do you think that it's looking in the same directory?

Comment: I've never used apache or wsgi, I don't know the aplication flow and am confused by what points where. This app was a functioning app on a server running on localhost in a vm but I am trying to switch it over to an apache server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the correct path of `json` file, you can try with [open_resource](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.open_resource):

```
with app.open_resource('client_secrets.json') as f:    
    CLIENT_ID = json.load(f)['web']['client_id']
```

or directly use the path:

```
import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
json_url = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'client_secrets.json')
CLIENT_ID = json.load(open(json_url))['web']['client_id']
```

Comment: Read the mod_wsgi documentation for more details around issue of what the application working directory is and the need to construct absolute pathnames. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory